# How to place a div using bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-5, dash-bootstrap-components

I want to place div one after another, in different directions like below linked image. [image]

Which bootstrap components can use get exact same design? Do you know any design ideas please guide me.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at the documentation. However, you can do this using flexboxes.

```html
<html>
<head>
<link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
   <div>Hire a Car</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
   <div>Buy a car</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
   <div>Sale a Car</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

For more information: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/#justify-content